# Boost Try lock Assert

Tags: boost, mutex

I am using boost::recursive_mutex. But when I use try_lock on this for the first time I am getting following error

CollisionAvoidance: /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:78: bool boost::recursive_mutex::try_lock(): Assertion `!res || res==16' failed.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem I have tried to lock the mutex before creating it. It did not segfault but failed to acquire...